# Common sense - Datagrid NoSQL vs. Plain SQL

Tags: java, php, javascript, oracle, extjs

My developer sense is tingling to just use plain SQL (JDBC) for a application which in 95% of the case will show a datagrid (extJS), with simple CRUD + compare functionality.
Looking into the buzz word NoSQL, I do not see any benefit... am I wrong?

If I want to lookup in my datagrid collection for a certain value ('john') in a certain column ('firstname') of a document in NoSQL (key/value collection)... great chance that I will create a separate collection for just **firstnames** for this query request and referencing to my datagrid collection.

Comment: http://geekandpoke.typepad.com/geekandpoke/2011/01/nosql.html :)

Comment: at first you sure file system is faster than NOSQL and then i think check mongodb ... its good nosql have filesystem (gridfs) also i can say NOSQL is many time faster than sql

Comment: Looks like, the default setup should be in a trusted environment for MongoDB http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Security+and+Authentication. So one of the benefits will be lots of speed, even with the setup I mentioned? (query per column collection)? Hmm gonna try it out with 100 million documents/tuples.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with cassandra, I can tell is faster than SQL. I guess for a Datagrid, NOSQL solution is gonna work much better cause you can group the columns in a way that they can be accesed in a secuential way in memory, so of course is faster.

Hope this helps,
Cheers

Comment: Care to provide an example what you mean with grouping of the columns? For decimal value.. I guess it would be more difficult, especially if you go need have a precise number e.g. (234.3415513) in a large dataset

Comment: What I mean is that you have 5 columns of your grid for example which are showed one behind the other, you can create a column family in the order you will access it. It will put it in memory one behind the other and the reading will be faster. The Data inside is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, SQL is the way to go until you have a very good reason to choose NoSQL. Mind that buzz certainly isn't such a reason ;) Everything starting from tools, developers, resources, products and even standards are mature for SQL. While NoSQL's main selling point is performance, performance rarely is key for a RDBMS. And if it seems to be, it rarely is the RDBMS's fault.

Comment: Yes... place the blame on the poorly or overly-engineered schemas instead!

Comment: well said!  Good db design is often overlooked or ignored altogether!